# Blazor SignalR Message Throttling

Tags: .net, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side, azure-signalr

I am currently looking to deploy Blazor Server applications into an Azure Kubernetes Cluster, using Azure SignalR Service to multiplex our client connections to our application pods. We have a concern in regards to a single client connection being able to initiate as many events as they wish once a websocket connection is established. For example, spamming a submit button thousands of times.

In Blazor Server is there any way to globally throttle the number of SignalR messages we will accept until forcefully disconnecting the circuit to prevent DDoS/DDoW attacks?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.